# how to check title of uibutton

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

```
NSString *title=btn.titleLabel.text; 

NSLog(@"Title=%@",title); 

if(title == @"SelectCategory") 
{
    //alert    
}
else
{
    //somecode
}
```

I want to check title of UIButton. But my code always executing else statement.

What is the error in this code?

Comment: You might want to look into some code formatting standards...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never compare two strings using '==', use [isEqualToString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-isEqualToString_)

```
if ([title isEqualToString:@"SelectCategory"]){
   //alert
}else{
   //somecode
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this line:

```
If([btn.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Your text"])
{
//do this
}
else
{
//do this
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *title=[btn currentTitle];

if([title isEqualToString:@"SelectCategory"])
{
  NSLog(@"Equal");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
if ([title isEqualToString:@"SelectCategory"]) {}
```

instead of `==` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Use bun.title is Equalto:@"" it will work for you.
Welcome

Comment: @Krishna is Correct use same code you will find your the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

Never use `==` to compare strings, with `==` you're checking if the pointer of a string is the same of another string, and it's not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UIButton *YourButton=btn;    

if([[YourButton titleForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqualToString:@"SelectCategory"])
{
        // normal
}
else if([[YourButton titleForState:UIControlStateHighlighted] isEqualToString:@"SelectCategory"])
{
        //highlighted
}
else if([[YourButton titleForState:UIControlStateSelected] isEqualToString:@"SelectCategory"])
{
        //selected
}
else
{
        //somecode
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two strings or two objects cannot be compared using `==`. To compare two objects you should use `isEqual`.

In this case :

```
if([stringToBeCompared isEqualToString:@"comparestring"])
{
   //statement
}
```